# Can I still get Steam achievements if mods are enabled on GTA V?

Tags: pc, achievements, grand-theft-auto-v, mods

I am about to mod my copy of *GTA V*. However, I am unsure if this will affect achievements, in case I accidentally earn some while modded.

If I were to play a modded *GTA V*, can I still earn achievements? And if not, can I still regain them if they were accidentally taken when mods were activated?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Modding *GTA V* won't affect the earning of Steam achievements. I was able to attain 100% completion and earn achievements, including [Career Criminal](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Career_Criminal), in *GTA V* on Steam despite my game being modded.